# Problem with breaking line in align mode

Tags: align

Here is the issue and here is the code.

```
\begin{align*}
\left ( \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}+ i \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}} \right )^{72} &=  \left [ \left ( \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \right )+ i \left ( \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \right ) \right ]^{72}\\ 
 &=\left [ \left ( \cos \frac{\pi}{3}\cos \frac{\pi}{4} + \sin \frac{\pi}{3}\sin \frac{\pi}{4} \right ) +i \left ( \sin \frac{\pi}{3} \cos \frac{\pi}{4} - \cos \frac{\pi}{3} \sin \frac{\pi}{4}  \right ) \right ]^{72} \\ 
 &= \left [ \cos \left ( \frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\pi}{4} \right ) +i \sin \left ( \frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\pi}{4} \right )\right ]^{72}\\ 
 &= \left ( \cos \frac{\pi}{12} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{12} \right )^{72}\\ 
 &= \left ( \cos^2 \frac{\pi}{12} - \sin^2 \frac{\pi}{12} +2i \cos \frac{\pi}{12} \sin \frac{\pi}{12} \right )^{36}\\ 
 &=\left ( \cos \frac{\pi}{6} + i \sin \frac{\pi}{6} \right )^{36} \\ 
 &= \left ( \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{i}{2} \right )^{36} \\
 &=\left [ \left ( \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+ \frac{i}{2} \right )^3 \right ]^{12} \\
 &=1
\end{align*}
```

The line

```
\left [ \left ( \cos \frac{\pi}{3}\cos \frac{\pi}{4} + \sin \frac{\pi}{3}\sin \frac{\pi}{4} \right ) +i \left ( \sin \frac{\pi}{3} \cos \frac{\pi}{4} - \cos \frac{\pi}{3} \sin \frac{\pi}{4}  \right ) \right ]^{72}
```

however exceeds the margins of the page so I want to break it. I used `\\` and then on the new line `&` plus two `\qquad` to bring it in a favor position and altough it gets a result the compile ends up with errors which is something logical. The output is that the final `]` in that line is not depicted at all.

How can I break up that line? Need I use `alignat` package?

Comment: Try with `\bigg[` and `\bigg]` instead of `\left[` and `\right]`. Should produce what you want. There's also `\big[` `\big]` if you want slightly smaller brackets.

Comment: @Grimler `\biggl[` and `\biggr]` to get correct open and close spacing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I really admire some people that give a link here to a possible duplicate. I searched and searched but in vain. Thanks.

Comment: @Grimler and David Carlisle ... Thank you both. I guess what David suggests is a little better. I'll adopt that one.

Comment: @Tolaso usually it is easier to search for the answer than search for the question, but then if you can do that you don't need to ask:-)

Comment: @Tolaso, yes. David's suggestion is definitely more correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am going ahead and answering this question of mine, again... :)*

As suggested by Grimler and David Carlisle the answer would be:

```
\biggl[ ... \biggr]
```

so that we have a better open and close spacing. Then at the point we are breaking the line we insert `\\` and the new line we also insert `&` so that we have the alignment and if necessary some space commands e.g `\quad , \qquad` or whatever so that the new expression comes to a favor position.

That depends on what someone likes.